# Only allow certain ip addresses to register a user in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to only allow certain ip addresses to access the register route, but I'm getting Type error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::showRegistrationForm() must
>   be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in
>   directory\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
>   on line 19

Here is my `showRegistrationForm` method in `AuthController`:

```
public function showRegistrationForm(Request $request) {
    $ip = $request->ip();

    if ($ip == "148.124.0.1") {
        return redirect("register");
    } else {
        return redirect("home");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Comment: What do you get when you dd($request)?

Comment: Are testing it from your local environment

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ yes I am.

Comment: it would be good if you add a middle-ware and apply for routes where ever u needed so no need to check in controller

Comment: @Frisbetarian I think it's failing before it enters the showRegistrationForm method in AuthController, because it's a different signature to the showRegistrationForm in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php trait.

Comment: Are you sure you're on Laravel 5.2?

Comment: Why would you want program logic based on IP anyway?  They're changeable and easily spoofed and as a general rule should have more or less nothing depending on them.

Comment: @Frisbetarian my version is Laravel Framework version 5.2.21 when doing php artisan --version in the command prompt.

Comment: I agree with @jdl134679 what you can do all crated account should be disabled as default and an administrator should activte users afterward

Comment: btw I tried you logic from route it works on my computer, you do not even need a contoller to check it.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I only want 1 or 2 people to be able to access the register users form, that's why I was basing it on ip addresses.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Instead checking in controller please check this way

```
php artisan make:middleware IpMiddleware
```

Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IpMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->ip() != "192.168.0.155") {
        // here instead of checking a single ip address we can do collection of ips
        //address in constant file and check with in_array function
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

then add the new middleware class in the $`middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'ipcheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\IpMiddleware::class,
];
```

then apply middelware to routes

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => ['ipcheck'], function () {
    // your routes here
}]);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @pramod kadam, I'll try this approach.

Comment: Thanks.. just to add to this, if you have a public repository like mine, it's better to use `.env` to store that ip address...

Comment: `'ipcheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\Ip::class`, should be  `'ipcheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\IpMiddleware::class`

Comment: There are a few mistakes in the routes section. It needs to be: `Route::group(['middleware' => 'ipcheck'], function () {
    //your routes here
});`

Comment: Can you use a CIDR block of ips without having to list all 1000 IPs?

Comment: @happymacarts Yes, we can use CIDR block, here I have given middleware example only.

Comment: @pramodkadam if i wanted to use this in a middleware and use a CIDR block how would I include those addresses? just use "1.1.1.1/24" ? or whatever my block was?

Comment: I've used the IP utilities library that's built-in to handle all kinds of IP formats: 
`use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\IpUtils;`
`IpUtils::checkIp($request->ip(), "1.1.1.1/24");`

Answer (score 12):

// .env

```
WHITELIST='192.168.1.1;192.168.1.2'
```

// access.php

```
whitelist => env('WHITELIST')
```

// WhitelistMiddleware.php

```
class WhitelistMiddleware
{
 /**
  * @param Request $request
  * @param Closure $next
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
  * @throws ForbiddenException
  */
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {

     $whitelist = config('access.whitelist');

     $ipAddresses = explode(';', $whitelist);

      if (! in_array($request->ip(), $ipAddresses)) {

        \Log::error('IP address is not whitelisted', ['ip address', $request->ip()]);

        return redirect('home');
     }

     return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Akongnwi, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on your middleware logic:

```php
// If system bypas on proxy (E.g load balancer, nginx proxy, etc)
// X-FORWARDED-FOR
$remoteAddress = $request->header('X-FORWARDED-FOR');
// or 
$remoteAddress = $request->header('X-FORWARDED-FOR') ?? $request->header('REMOTE-ADDR');

// Default remote address
// REMOTE-ADDR
$remoteAddress = $request->header('REMOTE-ADDR');

$allowedAddresses = [
    '192.168.1.50',
    '192.17.1.50/24',
    '10.17.0.0/16',
];

if (!\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\IpUtils::checkIp($remoteAddress, $allowedAddresses)) {
    abort(403); // By security proposes, I use 404 (prevent bots)
}

// All right. Is allowed
```